# R mapply 計算速度について

Tags: r

mapplyで下記計算を行っています。

```
function <- function(x, y){....}

param1 <- seq(1, 50, by = 0.5)
param2 <- seq(1, 50, by = 0.5)
param <- expand.grid(param1, param2)

data <- rep(NA, nrow(param))

data <- mapply(FUN = function, x = param$Var1, y = param$Var2, SIMPLIFY = TRUE, USE.NAMES = TRUE)
```

総当たり計算においてはmapplyは非常に強力かと思いますが、計算時間が非常に長くなっています。

並列化をすれば若干は計算時間が短くなると聞いていますが、mapplyの並列化はどのように行えば良いのでしょうか。

ご教授頂けると幸いです。

Comment: parallel パッケージに `mcmapply()` がありますので、そちらを使うと良いかもしれません。[Parallel Versions of 'lapply' and 'mapply' using Forking](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/parallel/html/mclapply.html)

Comment: 早速確認させて頂きます。有難う御座いました。